# What is this matrix sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, recurrence-relations

Say I have two square matrices $A$ and $P$. My series is as follows:

$$\begin{aligned} X_1 &= P\\ X_2 &= PA+A^TP\\ &\vdots\\ X_R &= X_{R-1}A+A^T X_{R-1}\end{aligned}$$

What function is this? It is fairly similar to the binomial expansion, 
since the coefficients of the expanded terms lead to the Pascal triangle, yet it is somewhat different.

Comment: It seems that $$X_k = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{\ell} \left( A^\top \right)^\ell P A^{k-1-\ell}$$ which suggests that one should redefine $X_0 := P$. This recurrence relation reminds me of the [anticommutator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Anticommutator.html).

Comment: I believe you're right. The very interesting thing is that your result is equivalent to Greg's. If someone would have told me that there was a way to write a matrix binomial expansion as a matrix exponential, I would have just laughed at him before this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix equation
$$X_{k+1} = X_kA + A^TX_k$$
can be converted (by [column stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)) into a vector equation
$$\eqalign{
x_{k+1}
 &= \left(A^T\otimes I+I\otimes A^T\right) x_k \\
 &\doteq (B+C)x_k \\
 &= (B+C)^kp \\
}$$
So it is a binomial expansion of $(B+C)$

In general matrix multiplication is non-commutative, however these particular matrices do commute, so the expansion can be treated exactly like the scalar case.

And should $(B+C)^k$ converge to a limit
$$\eqalign{
  L &= \lim_{k\to\infty}(B+C)^k \\
  x &= \lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k+1} = Lp \\
}$$

Comment: To know the solution in terms of matrices would it be possible to do an anti-vectirization?

Comment: @MirkoAveta In MATLAB, anti-vectorization can be done using function `reshape`.

Comment: How about finding the fixed point via the linear system $\bar{x} = (B+C) \bar{x}$?